# Unable to lock SQL Server AD account from C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am looking to programmatically lock an account on a database server. I have hundreds of them to do so I need a programmatic solution.

I am running the following 2 commands

```
string query = "ALTER LOGIN [" + itemJson.Account + "] DISABLE;";
query = "USE MASTER DENY CONNECT SQL TO [" + itemJson.Account + "];";
```

which turns into

```
ALTER LOGIN [TestAccount] DISABLE;
USE MASTER DENY CONNECT SQL TO [TestAccount];
```

and it works great.

However if I change the commands to

```
ALTER LOGIN [domain\TestAccount] DISABLE;
USE MASTER DENY CONNECT SQL TO [domain\TestAccount];
```

The process fails with

> Cannot alter the login 'domain\TestAccount', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

If I run the same commands in SSMS running as the same account as the application it works perfectly fine.

Any thoughts or recommendations?

Comment: Probably wrong connection string. I.e. the specified user therein does not have sufficient permissions.

Comment: I am confident that it is the proper connection string since I can lock a SQL authenticated account with the same connection string.

Comment: Does it make more sense to disable the account on the AD side? Does the AD account need to stay active in general and only be disabled on the database side? I'm thinking ALTER LOGIN isn't appropriate for AD accounts.

Comment: That is correct. We are looking to kick certain people out of the database, but not kick them out of the company.

Comment: ALTER LOGIN statement requires ALTER ANY LOGIN permission

Comment: The account I am using is in the SA role. Its only when I try in .net do I run into the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, just to answer what was going on.

I was keeping json in my database that contained the value.

{"Instance":"Server","Database":"Database","Account":"Domain\TestAccount"}

When I brought this into the application I was using Newtonsoft to convert the json into an object. Unfortunately, the conversion saw \t and turned account into "Domain   estAccount".

I reset the json to Domain\TestAccount and it fixed the problem.

Thanks for your help.